# Is there a Software package or API available for street address completion?

Tags: web-services, google-maps, autocomplete, openstreetmap, street-address

Does anyone know of a service (free or paid) or software that I can host for street address completion? I'm interested in providing a list of possible completions for an address string, not geocoding an address.

For example, if a user types "120 An", the service might provide 10 possible completions for that address string (i.e. "120 Anne Way NYC NY, 120 Anteater St. Seattle WA... etc.")

Ideally I would be able to constrain the list of returned addresses to a particular region.

Openstreetmaps had "Name finder" a while ago but it doesn't look like it exists anymore.

---

I should mention I'm open to hosting the service myself. I believe I can extract the list of region specific addresses from Openstreetmap data, I need an API to put them in though...

Comment: [USPS has an API.](https://www.usps.com/business/webtools.htm) I don't think it's capable of doing exactly what you ask but it can verify an address.

Comment: @jk. Yeah, looks like they only have address verification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [Google Places autocomplete API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete) .

Comment: I found this as well. Thanks. I thought Google's terms of service required that the Places API be used with a Google Map, but this does not appear to be the case. You can use the autocomplete API with just a google logo on your form.

Answer (score 2):

[SmartyStreets](http://smartystreets.com) just finished a new autocomplete feature, and it's totally free with an API subscription (which is also free, to a point). I work at SmartyStreets and helped to develop it.

[image: SmartyStreets address autocomplete]

You can put it on your website with [the jQuery plugin](http://smartystreets.com/kb/liveaddress-api/website-forms). It works very well for US addresses. For international, Google might be your best bet, where license restrictions don't get in the way.

Comment: No, but it can accept firm names as part of the input in some cases.